# What does "quick and dirty hack" by Heiko Oberdiek do?

Tags: hyperref, indexing, imakeidx

In my document's preamble I have the following code related to `showidx` and `hyperref`, which also appears in many posts on this forum.

What is its purpose?

```
%Begin the ``quick and dirty hack'' due to Heiko Oberdiek which loads showidx
\makeatletter
\ifHy@hyperindex
  \def\HyInd@ParenLeft{(}%
% Hook in \HyInd@@wrindex
  \let\HyInd@showidx\@empty
% Hook in \HyInd@@wrindex for package showidx
  \def\HyInd@showidx#1{%
    \@showidx{#1}%
    \if@nobreak
      \ifvmode
        \nobrak
      \fi
    \fi
  }%
% Load package showidx
  \let\siOrg@makeindex\makeindex
  \let\siOrg@@index\@index
  \let\siOrg@@wrindex\@wrindex
  \let\siOrg@index\index
  \RequirePackage{showidx}
  \let\makeindex\siOrg@makeindex
  \let\@index\siOrg@@index
  \let\@wrindex\siOrg@@wrindex
  \let\index\siOrg@index
% rest of hyperref part
  \@ifpackageloaded{multind}{%
    \let\HyInd@org@wrindex\@wrindex
    \def\@wrindex#1#2{\HyInd@@wrindex{#1}#2||\\}%
    \def\HyInd@@wrindex#1#2|#3|#4\\{%
      \ifx\\#3\\%
        \HyInd@org@wrindex{#1}{#2|hyperpage}%
      \else
        \def\Hy@temp@A{#3}%
        \ifx\Hy@temp@A\HyInd@ParenLeft
          HyInd@org@wrindex{#1}{#2|#3hyperpage}%
        \else
          \HyInd@org@wrindex{#1}{#2|#3}%
        \fi
      \fi
    }%
  }{%
    \def\@wrindex#1{\@@wrindex#1||\\}
    \def\@@wrindex#1|#2|#3\\{%
      \ifx\\#2\\%
        \protected@write\@indexfile{}{%
          \string\indexentry{#1|hyperpage}{\thepage}%
        }%
      \else
        \def\Hy@temp@A{#2}%
        \ifx\Hy@temp@A\HyInd@ParenLeft
          \protected@write\@indexfile{}{%
             \string\indexentry{#1|#2hyperpage}{\thepage}%
          }%
        \else
          \protected@write\@indexfile{}{%
            \string\indexentry{#1|#2}{\thepage}%
          }%
        \fi
      \fi
      \endgroup
      \HyInd@showidx{#1}%
      \@esphack
    }%
  }%
\fi
\makeatother
%
%End the ``quick and dirty hack'' due to Heiko Oberdiek which loads showidx
```

Among posts where this appears are: [How to refer to indexed words](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/393821/how-to-refer-to-indexed-words), [TOC, Chapter Toc, and Appendix misfunctions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313209/toc-chapter-toc-and-appendix-misfunctions), [How to restate a theorem keeping the same number?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348263/how-to-restate-a-theorem-keeping-the-same-number/348279#348279), [How to display index entries on the same line as the text being indexed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/292100/how-to-display-index-entries-on-the-same-line-as-the-text-being-indexed), [Distinguish forward cross-references from backward cross-references](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/410362/distinguish-forward-cross-references-from-backward-cross-references).

Comment: Can you post a reference? Out of context like this is hard to tell...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was created as an answer to the question

```
hyperref appears to be trashing the index of my article document.
Without hyperref (which I really need), the index, generated
with makeidx package commands \makeindex and \printindex, looks great. 
With hyperref, which I tend to load with these options,

\usepackage[plainpages=false,hyperindex]{hyperref}

the index is collapsed from hundreds of entries with various page
numbers down to a single entry
```

For more insight see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.text.tex/fof9f-cln-I

However tested 18 years later "the quick fix" (included in full below) is still needed to correct hyperref especially working with showidx with  \documentclass{article}. **Also** see comment by @murry below suggesting there may be other cases for its use

"**And with the memoir** documentclass, where showidx is not explicitly loaded, but rather emulated by `memoir` ?"  - murry

I am also including comments from Ulrike with reference to this from a deleted duplicate answer about its continued use.

"The hack has not been added to `hyperref`, and depending on the loading order either `showidx` or the hyperlinks from the index break. I don't think that the latter is really a problem as one doesn't need `showidx` for the final version of a document. I tested with Heiko's example in the google.groups you linked to after removing the hack (but leaving `showidx`). – Ulrike Fischer

[image]

Here is the source test file (in case the above link is lost)

```
%%% cut %%% test.tex %%% cut %%%
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\ifHy@hyperindex
  \def\HyInd@ParenLeft{(}%
% Hook in \HyInd@@wrindex
  \let\HyInd@showidx\@empty
% Hook in \HyInd@@wrindex for package showidx
  \def\HyInd@showidx#1{%
    \@showidx{#1}%
    \if@nobreak
      \ifvmode
        \nobrak
      \fi
    \fi
  }%
% Load package showidx
  \let\siOrg@makeindex\makeindex
  \let\siOrg@@index\@index
  \let\siOrg@@wrindex\@wrindex
  \let\siOrg@index\index
  \RequirePackage{showidx}
  \let\makeindex\siOrg@makeindex
  \let\@index\siOrg@@index
  \let\@wrindex\siOrg@@wrindex
  \let\index\siOrg@index
% rest of hyperref part
  \@ifpackageloaded{multind}{%
    \let\HyInd@org@wrindex\@wrindex
    \def\@wrindex#1#2{\HyInd@@wrindex{#1}#2||\\}%
    \def\HyInd@@wrindex#1#2|#3|#4\\{%
      \ifx\\#3\\%
        \HyInd@org@wrindex{#1}{#2|hyperpage}%
      \else
        \def\Hy@temp@A{#3}%
        \ifx\Hy@temp@A\HyInd@ParenLeft
          HyInd@org@wrindex{#1}{#2|#3hyperpage}%
        \else
          \HyInd@org@wrindex{#1}{#2|#3}%
        \fi
      \fi
    }%
  }{%
    \def\@wrindex#1{\@@wrindex#1||\\}
    \def\@@wrindex#1|#2|#3\\{%
      \ifx\\#2\\%
        \protected@write\@indexfile{}{%
          \string\indexentry{#1|hyperpage}{\thepage}%
        }%
      \else
        \def\Hy@temp@A{#2}%
        \ifx\Hy@temp@A\HyInd@ParenLeft
          \protected@write\@indexfile{}{%
             \string\indexentry{#1|#2hyperpage}{\thepage}%
          }%
        \else
          \protected@write\@indexfile{}{%
            \string\indexentry{#1|#2}{\thepage}%
          }%
        \fi
      \fi
      \endgroup
      \HyInd@showidx{#1}%
      \@esphack
    }%
  }%
\fi
\makeatother

\makeindex
\begin{document}
\section{Hello World}
Hello\index{Hello} World\index{World}
\newpage
\index{abc}
abc def
\printindex
\end{document}
%%% cut %%% test.tex %%% cut %%%
```

Comment: And with the `memoir` documentclass, where `showidx` is not explicitly loaded, but rather emulated by `memoir`?