# Is Oberdiek's hack still needed for showidx with hyperref?

Tags: hyperref, memoir, indexing

Is the following code still needed...

1. To allow `showidx` to work with `hyperref' for`book`,`article` document classes?
2. To allow the emulation of `showidx` in the `memoir` document class to work with `hyperref`? In fact, does it actually do anything with `memoir`, or only with the free-standing `showidx`?

```
%Begin the ``quick and dirty hack'' due to Heiko Oberdiek which loads showidx
\makeatletter
\ifHy@hyperindex
  \def\HyInd@ParenLeft{(}%
% Hook in \HyInd@@wrindex
  \let\HyInd@showidx\@empty
% Hook in \HyInd@@wrindex for package showidx
  \def\HyInd@showidx#1{%
    \@showidx{#1}%
    \if@nobreak
      \ifvmode
        \nobrak
      \fi
    \fi
  }%
% Load package showidx
  \let\siOrg@makeindex\makeindex
  \let\siOrg@@index\@index
  \let\siOrg@@wrindex\@wrindex
  \let\siOrg@index\index
  \RequirePackage{showidx}
  \let\makeindex\siOrg@makeindex
  \let\@index\siOrg@@index
  \let\@wrindex\siOrg@@wrindex
  \let\index\siOrg@index
% rest of hyperref part
  \@ifpackageloaded{multind}{%
    \let\HyInd@org@wrindex\@wrindex
    \def\@wrindex#1#2{\HyInd@@wrindex{#1}#2||\\}%
    \def\HyInd@@wrindex#1#2|#3|#4\\{%
      \ifx\\#3\\%
        \HyInd@org@wrindex{#1}{#2|hyperpage}%
      \else
        \def\Hy@temp@A{#3}%
        \ifx\Hy@temp@A\HyInd@ParenLeft
          HyInd@org@wrindex{#1}{#2|#3hyperpage}%
        \else
          \HyInd@org@wrindex{#1}{#2|#3}%
        \fi
      \fi
    }%
  }{%
    \def\@wrindex#1{\@@wrindex#1||\\}
    \def\@@wrindex#1|#2|#3\\{%
      \ifx\\#2\\%
        \protected@write\@indexfile{}{%
          \string\indexentry{#1|hyperpage}{\thepage}%
        }%
      \else
        \def\Hy@temp@A{#2}%
        \ifx\Hy@temp@A\HyInd@ParenLeft
          \protected@write\@indexfile{}{%
             \string\indexentry{#1|#2hyperpage}{\thepage}%
          }%
        \else
          \protected@write\@indexfile{}{%
            \string\indexentry{#1|#2}{\thepage}%
          }%
        \fi
      \fi
      \endgroup
      \HyInd@showidx{#1}%
      \@esphack
    }%
  }%
\fi
\makeatother
%
%End the ``quick and dirty hack'' due to Heiko Oberdiek which loads showidx
```

As noted in [What does "quick and dirty hack" by Heiko Oberdiek do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/492874/what-does-quick-and-dirty-hack-by-heiko-oberdiek-do), that code appears in examples in a number of posts.

Comment: Huh... Isn't this the same question as this https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/492874/134574 ?